# how to use :: before and ::after in an xpath?

Tags: xpath

I have an xpath that selects the correct 'section' of text, in that it goes to the correct `<div>`s, however it includes `::before` and `::after` which I am not familiar with.

The structure is something like (changes on different parts of the site)

```
<div>
     ::before
          formatting "stuff i dont want" formatting
     ::after
          formattin "stuff i do want" formatting
     <br>
          formatting "more stuff i want" formatting
<div>
```

my problem is that i am unfamiliar with `::before and after` and also that i get separate entries, including '/r/n', so from the above i get about 10 entries (depends again on the formatting of the site) where i only want one.

Is there a way to get an output like `"stuff i do want more stuff i want"` which I append to a list, and my list should have length of 1.

My current expath gives me

`'\r\n', '\r\n', '  ', "stuff i don't want", '  ', ' stuff i do want', '  ', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', "more stuff i want", '  ', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n`

Comment: `::before` and `::after` are not part of XPath. They are simply *string* expressions. So handle them with `substring-before` and `substring-after`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure using XPath is the most elegant way to get your desired output. Some clues assuming you're using scrappy and Python :

XPath only solution with `concat()`,`normalize-space()`,`substring-after()`,`substring-before()` functions :

```
concat(normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(//div/text()[normalize-space()][1],'formatting "'),'" formatting'))," ",normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(//div/text()[normalize-space()][2],'formatting "'),'" formatting'))).get()
```

Output :

```
stuff i do want more stuff i want
```

XPath combined with regex solution :

```
import re
text = normalize-space(//div).get()
data = re.findall('"(.+?)"', text, re.IGNORECASE)
print(" ".join(data))
```

Output :

```
stuff i do want more stuff i want
```